# Eventbrite PHP RSVP

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, sdk, eventbrite

I have a list of our Eventbrite events inside our PHP CodeIgniter web app.

Here's the code fo my events list:

```
<?php
  $token = "our_token";
  $organizer_id =  "our_organizer_id";
  $request_url = "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?sort_by=date&organizer.id=".$organizer_id."&token=".$token;
  $params = array('sort_by' => 'date', 'organizer.id' => $organizer_id, 'token' => $token);
  $context = stream_context_create(
               array(
                     'http' => array(
                       'method'  => 'GET',
                       'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                     )
               )
             );
  $json_data = file_get_contents( $request_url, false, $context );
  $response = json_decode($json_data, true);
?>
```

I used `$response` inside a loop so I could display them. Here's what it looks like.[image]

Now, I want the users to be able to RSVP inside the system and not by redirecting through Eventbrite. [**Here**](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/brunchwork-w-vogue-eniac-ventures-tickets-49444046474?aff=ebdssbdestsearch)'s a sample event from the list.

I know it's possible but how can I make it work?
This is my first time to work on Eventbrite and their official documentation is in Python. I already emailed their support if they could provide me a good documentation in PHP but I haven't heard from them.

Although there's an SDK and some libraries available, I don't how how to use them and some of them with examples are deprecated.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via Eventbrite's API endpoints. However, you can use Eventbrite's embedded checkout widget to accomplish this.

Here are the Eventbrite Articles on Embedded Checkout:

https://www.eventbrite.com/support/articles/en_US/Multi_Group_How_To/how-to-sell-eventbrite-tickets-on-your-website-through-an-embedded-checkout?lg=en_US

https://www.eventbrite.com/support/articles/en_US/How_To/how-to-add-eventbrite-s-embedded-checkout-to-your-wordpress-org-site?lg=en_US

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks @nathan but that's not what I need. I created a test app and was able to create an authentication process. Can that be used to RSVP inside the system? I mean the payment can stay in Eventbrite.